# Ordering faceted bar chart in 3 ways - X, color, facets

Tags: bar-chart, categories, plotly-python, plotly-express

I need to control the ordering of displayed values in 3 ways at the same time:
xaxis, color and facets.

Plotly web-site has similar example to my problem:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.bar(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker", barmode="group", facet_col="sex",
category_orders={"day": ["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
>                               "smoker": ["Yes", "No"],
>                               "sex": ["Male", "Female"]})
fig.show()
```

I need to control these category_orders "day/smoker/sex" not with a list of values, but just with "ascending/descending/ascending".

The part with xaxis can be solved like this:

```
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='category ascending')
```

But i have no I idead about other two parameters.

Is it possible to set asc/desc/asc for all 3 just inside the initial px.bar(...) code?
If not, please, advice how that can be done in any other way.

Comment: How do you order the day in ascending order? Do you mean alphabetically?

Comment: yes, alphabetically. do not look at this as a "real" day. I just use the code from Plotly site with similar structure. My actual data contains just normal words and is Ok to order asc/desc)))

Comment: Why don't you do all orders on dataframe before plotting it?

Comment: well, this is exactly the answer I got below.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to sort the data in the order you want it displayed. So... sort the data as Asc, Des, Asc and then plot. Updated code below...

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
df=df.sort_values(['day','smoker','sex'], ascending=[True,False, True])
fig = px.bar(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker", barmode="group", facet_col="sex")
fig.show()
```

**Output Plot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I came up with something similar :-) - extracting unique values of needed column, sorting them and assigning this order inside px.bar() with a variable.

df = px.data.tips()

ds=sorted(df['day'].unique(), reverse=True)


fig = px.bar(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker", barmode="group", facet_col="sex",

             category_orders={"day": ds,

                              "smoker": ["Yes", "No"],

                              "sex": ["Male", "Female"]})

fig.show()